# PythonのopenpyxlでExcelの行と列を入れ替え方法について

Tags: python, python3, excel, openpyxl

Python3でExcelファイルの行と列を入れ替えのですが、
実現したい内容が上手くいかないので質問させて頂きます。
ご指導をお願いできますでしょうか。

Excelのデータ

```
No      国    　　　　都市               ディズニーランド有/無
1       アメリカ      カリフォルニア      有
                      フロリダ　　　　　　有
2       フランス      パリ　　　　        有
3       日本          東京    　　　　    有
                      沖縄　　　　　　　　　
                      京都　　　　　　　　無
4       ブラジル      サンパウロ          無
```

#### Excelの行と列を入れ替えたい内容

1. 都市が幾つかがある場合、空白を削除して次の列に都市を移動したい
2. 「ディズニーランド有/無」の列に無や空白がある場合も行を削除したい

```
No（A列）     国（B列）   都市（C列）     都市2(D列）
1             アメリカ    カリフォルニア  フロリダ
2             フランス    パリ
3             日本        東京
```

下記のコードでやってみましたらこちらの結果が表示されます。

```
都市             カリフォルニア  フロリダ    パリ  東京  沖縄  京都  サンパウロ
ディズニーランド有/無 有         有      有   有      無     無
```

コード

```py
#openpyxlモジュールを使用する
import openpyxl
 
#既存のExcelファイルを開く
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")
#既存ファイルのシートを指定
sheet1=wb['Sheet1']
#既存ファイルに新規シートをシート名と位置を指定して作成
sheet2=wb.create_sheet(title='Sheet2',index=1)
 
#Sheet1の値のある行数を取得
rw=sheet1.max_row
#Sheet1の値のある列数を取得
cl=sheet1.max_column
 
#iは値のある行数分繰り返す
#jは値のある列数分繰り返す
#range(start,stop)はstart≦i<stopでstopで指定した値は含まないので「+1」している
for i in range(1,rw+1):
    for j in range(1,cl+1):
        C1=sheet1.cell(row=i,column=j) #sheet1のセルの行番号と列番号を指定している
        C2=sheet2.cell(row=j,column=i) #sheet1のセルの行番号と列番号を入れ替えてsheet2のセルを指定している
        C2.value=C1.value #sheet2のセルにsheet1のセルの値を代入
 
wb.save("test.xlsx") #上書き保存

# シートのロード
ws = wb.worksheets[1]

#シートの最終行を取得
Sheet_Max = ws.max_row + 1

#最終行から逆ループ
for i in reversed(range(1,Sheet_Max)):

    GetValue1 = ws.cell(row=i, column=3).value

    #A列が None だったら
    if GetValue1 == None:
        #行削除
        ws.delete_rows(i)
    else:
        #C列の空白文字を削除
        GetValue2 = GetValue1.strip()

        #セルの文字数が 0 だったら
        if len(GetValue2) == 0:
            #行削除
            ws.delete_rows(i)

wb.save("testdelete.xlsx") #上書き保存
```

Comment: 「行と列を入れ替え」という考え方を全体に適用しようとしているのが間違っていそうです。前提条件として「国の欄が空白ならその上の行と同じ国として扱う」とした上で、①ディズニーランドが「有」の行だけ残す、②ディズニーランド有/無の列を削除する、③同一国に複数の都市があったら、2つ目以後の都市名を後ろの列に移動し、1つの国では1つの行だけになるように変形させる。と言うことだと思われます。それで処理を考え直してみてください。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。下記の方法でもできました。

Comment: 一般的に「行と列の入れ替え」とは「縦と横を入れ替える」ことを指す事が多いので、今回の場合は単に「行列データの操作」くらいにしておいたほうが誤解が少ないと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下は Excel のシートを pandas のデータフレームに変換して [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) の `method='ffill'` を使う方法です。

```py
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

# convert to pandas dataframe
data = ws.values
cols = next(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

# fill in the forward
df[['No', '国']] = df[['No', '国']].fillna(method='ffill')
df.No = df.No.astype(int)

# select data
dfx = df[df['ディズニーランド有/無'] == '有']

print(dfx.to_markdown(index=False))

# save to a new sheet
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for r in dataframe_to_rows(dfx, index=False, header=True):
  ws.append(r)

wb.save('test_delete1.xlsx')
```

**Dataframe dfx**

| No | 国 | 都市 | ディズニーランド有/無 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | アメリカ | カリフォルニア | 有 |
| 1 | アメリカ | フロリダ | 有 |
| 2 | フランス | パリ | 有 |
| 3 | 日本 | 東京 | 有 |

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの方法も参考いたします。

Answer (score 0):

下記の方法でも解決できました。
他に良い方法でもあれば、教授をお願い致します。

①同一国に複数の都市があったら、2つ目以後の都市名を後ろの列に移動し、1つの国では1つつの行だけする
②ディズニーランド有/無の列の空白を削除する
③ディズニーランド有/無の列の無だけを削除する

code

```
import openpyxl

# Excelファイルを開く
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']

# a列の次の行が空白の場合、前のa列を代入
number = ''
for i in range(2,ws.max_row+1):
    if ws['a'+str(i)].value is None or not str(ws['a'+str(i)].value).strip():
        ws['a'+str(i)].value = number
    else:
        number = ws['a'+str(i)].value

# ｂ列の次の行が空白の場合、前のｂ列を代入
country = ''
for i in range(2,ws.max_row+1):
    if ws['b'+str(i)].value is None or not str(ws['b'+str(i)].value).strip():
        ws['b'+str(i)].value = country
    else:
        country = ws['b'+str(i)].value

#シートの最終行を取得
Sheet_Max = ws.max_row +1

#最終行から逆ループ
for i in reversed(range(Sheet_Max)):

    if i == 0:
        break

    #D列が空白だったら
    if ws.cell(row=i, column=4).value == None:

        #行削除
        ws.delete_rows(i)

#別名で保存
wb.save("test_delete1.xlsx")

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("test_delete1.xlsx")

ws = wb['Sheet1']

#シートの最終行を取得
Sheet_Max = ws.max_row + 1

#最終行から逆ループ
for i in reversed(range(Sheet_Max)):

    if i == 0:
        break

    #D列に特定の値が含まれていたら
    if '無' in ws.cell(row=i, column=4).value:

        #行削除
        ws.delete_rows(i)

wb.save("test_delete1.xlsx") #上書き保存
```

結果

```
1   アメリカ    カリフォルニア 有
1   アメリカ    フロリダ    　　 有
2   フランス    パリ          有
3   日本      東京          有
```